# Writing VBA to filter through OLAP Pivot Table Fields

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, olap-cube

I'm new to VBA. I have an excel file with a pivot table created by OLAP Cube.
I try to create a variable that filters a specific column within the Pivot Table.

I used Record Macro and this is what I've got:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Item].[ItemByProducer].[ProducerName]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Item].[ItemByProducer].[ProducerName].&[the name of the producer]")

End Sub
```

The macro works well for that specific producer, but I want to create a variable of type string in which I can filter by other producers also.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can concatenate the string with `&`: `"[Item].[ItemByProducer].[ProducerName].&[" & yourvariable & "]"`.

Comment: Actually this seemed to do the trick      Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Item].[ItemByProducer].[ProducerName]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Item].[ItemByProducer].[ProducerName].&["& stringvariable &"]")

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the variables in an array - `producers = Array("ProducerA", "ProducerB", "ProducerC")`

Then loop over them with the code below. Just make sure to change the name of `"NameOfWorksheet"` to the sheet you are using. `ActiveSheet` is not a good idea - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba):

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim producers As Variant
    producers = Array("ProducerA", "ProducerB", "ProducerC")
    Dim producer As Variant
    
    For Each producer In producers
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
            "[Item].[ItemByProducer].[ProducerName]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                "[Item].[ItemByProducer].[ProducerName].&[" & producer & "]")
    Next    

End Sub
```