# Cubefield items

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I am trying to set a specific value, specified in a cell of a sheet, for a CubeField of a power pivot. I can't enter the item as I would normally do with a simple pivot table, using the PivotItems method.

Here's the code.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim powerPivot As PivotTable
    Dim filterValue As String
    Dim fieldWeek As CubeField
    
    'Reference for the power pivot table
    Set powerPivot = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Channels").PivotTables("Channels")

    'Reference for a value contained in a cell
    filterValue = Worksheets("Cover").Range("G41").Value

    'Reference for a specific pivot field
    Set fieldWeek = powerPivot.CubeFields("[Calendar].[Year WeekNo]")
    
    'Clear of the field
    fieldWeek.ClearManualFilter

    'Here I would like to enter the item [Year WeekNo] and set the value as per my filterValue
    
End Sub
```

I don't want to change values in a pivot but just filter a value from a pivot field.

Moreover, I am not using a simple pivot table, but a power pivot table based on a OLAP model. This makes things harder because I can't use, for example, the object PivotFields.

Did anyone face a similar issue? I know that power pivots have some limitations with VB but I would like just to set a value, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

Please try. Modify as needed if the format of `Year WeekNo` is diferent.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim Yr As String, iWeek As Integer
    Dim arrItem(1 To 4)
    Yr = "2023"
    For iWeek = 10 To 13
        arrItem(iWeek - 9) = "[Calendar].[Year WeekNo].&[" & Yr & Chr(32) & iWeek & "]"
    Next
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields _
        ("[Calendar].[Year WeekNo].[Year WeekNo]").VisibleItemsList = arrItem
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I am managing a power pivot, do you think that PivotFields and CubeFields object fit together? I tried fieldWeek.PivotFields("Year WeekNo").PivotItems(CStr(filterValue)).Visible = True but it doesn't work

Comment: My code was tested with PowerPivot, unforunately I don't have OLAP model. Have you tried `VisibleItemsList`. Pls refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823298/writing-vba-to-filter-through-olap-pivot-table-fields

Comment: I tried it but the method VisibleItemsList is not included in the list of possibilities applicable to a CubeField